# Is it possible to make a video texture repeat in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have an animated overlay I want to use, and I have composited my project how I want, but I can't figure out how to make my animated overlays repeat. I want to know if there is a way to do this outside of the VSE if at all possible.

I am using the *Video Clip* node, but the video clip is only 57 frames long, and I need it to repeat for the full 400 frames of the animation. Can this be done outside of  the *Video Sequence Editor* in the video editing stages?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Can you provide any clarifying images?

Comment: Sure, just a sec

Comment: @Matt I edited the question to make it clearer, however I don't see what images would be at all helpful. Could you be more specific?

Comment: If I understand, I don't think what you're trying to do is possible without the VSE. That's what the VSE is for, putting video clips together. If you did use the VSE, you'd probably still have to use an Alpha Over or Alpha under to put your overlay on top of the other video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your video not using the **Movie Clip** Node but with the **Image Sequence** node (yes you can load video files in the image sequence clip).

Then enable the cyclic option and your video file will repeat on a loop.

[image]

Comment: **WOW!!** That is the most awesome thing ever!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Useful also to select which frames of the video clip you want ot use and to determine at what point in the scene youwant them to play. :)

Comment: how to loop it only 3 times instead of forever (cyclic)?

Comment: @juFo please ask this as a new question (use the blue  ASK QUESTION link on the top of the page)